# Why there is no tag for classical chess related questions?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

I wanted to ask a question related to the classical format of chess. To my surprise, I did not find any tag for the classical-related chess questions. It would be really great if any mod could create a classical tag for the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it wouldn't. Almost all questions on Chess Stack Exchange apply (or at least could apply) to classical chess. This would be an [intrinsic tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62183/295232) and have absolutely no value.